# Logging into Facebook. Callbacks for each permission request, onActivityResult force close

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to log into facebook with Facebooks Android SDK. I've set up a `Fragment` to do this. Since I need read permissions and publish permissions I am running my own callback. I get an error after accepting the first permission of `basic_info` and `user_birthday`. Here is the fragment I do it all in:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private final List<String> permissions;

public MainFragment() {
    permissions = Arrays.asList("basic_info", "user_birthday");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.FBButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        session.removeCallback(callback);
        session.addCallback(newCall);
        Log.i("MainFragment", "callback status called");
    }
};

private Session.StatusCallback newCall = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    Session.NewPermissionsRequest request = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        session.removeCallback(newCall);
        session.addCallback(new Session.StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {

                    //Running profile stuff
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            //In here I use the users profile information to send them to the correct activity.
                        }

                    }).executeAsync();

                }
            }
        });
Line 299:       session.requestNewPublishPermissions(request);
    }
}; 
}
```

Here is the error from my logcat:

```
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146): Process: com.package.name, PID: 17146
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.facebook.Session$AuthorizationRequest$1.startActivityForResult(Session.java:1660)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.facebook.Session.tryLoginActivity(Session.java:1167)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.facebook.Session.authorize(Session.java:917)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1022)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:512)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.package.name.MainFragment$2.call(MainFragment.java:299)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.facebook.Session$3$1.run(Session.java:1303)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-14 14:20:36.668: E/AndroidRuntime(17146):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I was told the error was because `uiHelper` doesn't know the activity I'm talking about. I'm unsure of what this means and how it could be fixed. Hopefully someone here can give me some advice on how to fix the error. Would really help, I get the feeling it's the last bit to getting this working. The first permission request shows up, I accept, then this happens.

I would really Appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some line numbers in your code

Comment: Line 299 seems to be the only one that points to something, I added that. The rest are not applicable. Line 95 is a space in the onResume method and Line 136 is a fully commented out method I am not using. Just before the first StatusCallback 'callback'.

Comment: You cant get a space (blank line) in a stack trace, it must be out of date

Comment: Sorry, it's commented out code that I have since removed. It's exactly like the code I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code must have been updated since you got that stack trace, based on the comment above.

If it is the line you have numbered then its likely the request is null as the session was used in previous lines. Check what Session.NewPermissionsRequest is returning, it may not like your data

Comment: There is so much to look at in a line by line debug that it's hard to follow. If I read it right, data = null after the first callback runs. DO you know if there's a better way to show in Logs to confirm this?

Comment: Right I'm getting somewhere at least. I put the Session.NewPermissionRequest into the public void call below it, just above removecallback(newCall). It calls the publish permission, I accept and then it runs the first callback again, on screen nothing happens after that. Exit the app and enter it again and I get a force close telling me an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.

Comment: If you are using android studio (and probably most IDEs) you can use all kinds of filters to reduce the logging and see just what matters. Your new issue sounds worth opening as a new question with your new code